# ASRock X570 Pro4 motherboard does not post, VGA / boot lights are solid

Tags: boot, cpu, motherboard, build

I put together a PC with the following components:

- ASRock X570 Pro4
- Ryzen 5 3600
- GTX 1660ti
- 2 ✕ 8GB DDR4 Corsair 3000MHz RAM
- 1 NVMe SSD (removed as it may not compatible)
- 1 micron SSD
- 500W gold certified power supply

When I power on I get no activity on display.

I tried so far:

- reseating RAM
- booting with 1 RAM stick
- HDMI port on mobo
- display port on mobo
- USB stick plugged into USB on mobo and also front panel USB with Windows 10 tool

Then removing GPU altogether and repeated the above.

- reseat CPU
- reset CMOS via jumper cap

Is there anything else I can check or try?

Comment: Did you figure this out?  I'm having the same issue... Even with no GPU installed it doesn't post.  This is my first AMD and so far, I'm not a fan.

Comment: Yeah my board was doa. I tried so many things trying to avoid sending it back but it was motherboard all along. Disappointing. Also, my first AMD kinda tough to start but it's great now

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but it only happened when I added a second GPU. I updated the BIOS firmware to th latest P1.40 & it solved my issues.